# Should NextJS Static Site Generation from Strapi CMS provide all the images, css, js files in the output folder when run from middle wear?

Tags: next.js, strapi

We have a middle-wear to run NextJS SSG when an something is published in Strapi.

The html files are created for each page and post in the output folder, but we do not see the CSS, JS, Images (from Strapi uploads).

Is this a multi-step process where we need to SSG the site and then pull all other files together or are we doing SSG incorrectly?